# Extracting a sub array from a Numpy array

Tags: numpy, image-processing, matplotlib

I have an image that's been loaded using `matplotlib.image.imread`.

What's the best way to extract the section of the image that begins at left column 20, row 5, and ends at right column 25, row 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem with `img[5:10,20:25]`?

```
import matplotlib.image as mi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = mi.imread('./3.png')
cropped =  img[5:10,20:25]
f,axarr = plt.subplots(2,1)
axarr[0].imshow(img)
axarr[1].imshow(cropped)
plt.show()
```

result:

[image]